# CarouselView's position stop work when Loop as False and ItemsSource Changed twice

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I Create a CarouselView,And set Loop as False,ItemsSource as a string List

At First,it works well.

But when I changed the ItemsSource of CarouselView for the Second time,The Position and CurrentItem and Related Events stop works

Once I Changed Loop of CarouselView as True,It will Recoverd as normal.

Once I Changed Loop of CarouselView as False,It will Has Problems.

In My App,I need Loop as False

I don't know whether the latest version of xamarin has solved this problem. My Xamarin.Form version is 5.0.0.2125

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Had you tried to use a mvvm and set a observablecollection<string> instead of sring list as the ItemSource?